# Failed to load chunks due to operation exceeded time limit

Tags: mongodb, database

We are facing Operation timed out and serverStatus was very slow issue, while accessing a collection.

Following are the errors,

```
db.collection.stats()
{ "code" : 50, 
  "ok" : 0, 
  "errmsg" : "Failed to load chunks due to operation exceeded time limit" 
}
```

Comment: Error Log - 1,
2017-08-30T08:46:23.418+0000 I NETWORK  [replSetDistLockPinger] Marking host histcfgsvr01:37020 as failed :: caused by :: ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out, request was RemoteCommand 5513 -- target:host:port db:config expDate:2017-08-30T08:46:23.418+0000 cmd:{ findAndModify: "lockpings", query: { _id: "host:port:1504077382:3669026758099117973" }, update: { $set: { ping: new Date(1504082753418) } }, upsert: true, writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 15000 }, maxTimeMS: 30000 }

Comment: Error Log - 2, 2017-08-30T08:46:46.008+0000 I SHARDING [Uptime reporter] Operation timed out with status ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out, request was RemoteCommand 5527 -- target:host:port db:config expDate:2017-08-30T08:46:46.008+0000 cmd:{ update: "mongos", updates: [ { q: { id: "host:port" }, u: { $set: { id: "host:port", ping: new Date(1504082776006), up: 5393, waiting: true, mongoVersion: "3.4.6" } }, multi: false, upsert: true } ], writeConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 15000 }, maxTimeMS: 30000 }

Comment: Error Log - 3, 2017-08-30T14:34:14.305+0000 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 0, after asserts: 0, after backgroundFlushing: 0, after connections: 0, after dur: 0, after extra_info: 3276, after globalLock: 3276, after locks: 3276, after network: 3276, after opLatencies: 3276, after opcounters: 3276, after opcountersRepl: 3276, after repl: 3276, after security: 3276, after storageEngine: 3276, after tcmalloc: 3276, after wiredTiger: 3276, at end: 3276 }

Comment: Please share all these in the question itself. Add meaning to it not comments.

Comment: Error Log - 4, 2017-08-31T03:35:33.217+0000 I NETWORK  [CatalogCacheLoader-10] Marking host host:port as failed :: caused by :: ExceededTimeLimit: operation exceeded time limit
2017-08-31T03:35:33.217+0000 I SHARDING [CatalogCacheLoader-10] Operation timed out  :: caused by :: ExceededTimeLimit: operation exceeded time limit
2017-08-31T03:35:33.217+0000 I SHARDING [CatalogCacheLoader-10] Refresh for collection Nova.Posting took 31318 ms and failed :: caused by :: ExceededTimeLimit: Failed to load chunks due to operation exceeded time limit

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: You might also discover the "edit" link on your question when you post on the correct network site. That's what you do when there is additional information to your post. "Comments" are the place for people asking you for clarification of details or notices such as above telling you that you are "in the wrong place".